# Out of 10 attendance sheets, how can I find the names that are present in at least 7 of them in Excel

Tags: excel

I have 10 attendance sheets in excel with only the names of present people. I want to find out which names are present in at least 7 sheets. How can I do this?

I know it is a terrible way to keep attendance and I wasn't the one who came up with it, I'm trying to salvage it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Join all lists into one. Create a pivottable.

Comment: Check out a post named "top 5" on here. Then are you really interested in those present or the ones missing…

Comment: Could you show what a sheet looks like? Is it only their names? Is it their full names? Or are the first and last name separated? Also, are there any students with the same first and last name?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this should do the trick. I threw it together so there are likely some efficiency improvements possible :)

Not sure what your structure is so I built this based on the simplest possible sheet, where there's a header row and students' names are shown when they attend. Students not in attendance are not listed. This probably doesn't match exactly but code should be easily tweaked. I can help if needed. You end up with an array called "arrGood" that contains the students and it'll pop up a message box telling you who met attendance or if no one did.

```
Option Explicit
Sub attendance()

'Set Variables
Dim sht As Integer, rw As Integer, pos As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer, goodAttendance As Integer
Dim arrClass() As Variant, arrTransfer() As Variant, arrGood() As Variant
Dim strName As String, strStudents As String
Dim inArray As Boolean

goodAttendance = 2 'change this if you want to check a different number

'Initialize empty arrays
ReDim arrClass(0, 1)
ReDim arrGood(0)

For sht = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count 'loop through worksheets
    For rw = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sht).Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'loop through rows starting with 2 (assuming there's a header row)
        inArray = False
        strName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sht).Cells(rw, 1).Value 'change this cell if searching for student names outside the first column
        'This section only triggers on the first run and adds the first student with attendance of 1
        If arrClass(0, 0) = "" Then
            arrClass(0, 0) = strName
            arrClass(0, 1) = 1
            inArray = True
        Else
            For pos = 0 To UBound(arrClass()) 'loop through array
                'check if student is already in array. Add 1 to their attendance if so
                If arrClass(pos, 0) = strName Then
                    inArray = True
                    arrClass(pos, 1) = arrClass(pos, 1) + 1
                End If
            Next pos
        End If
        If inArray = False Then 'new student not in array
            'Workaround to redim multidimensional array
            arrTransfer = arrClass
            ReDim arrClass(0 To UBound(arrClass) + 1, 1)
            For i = 0 To UBound(arrTransfer)
                For j = 0 To 1
                    arrClass(i, j) = arrTransfer(i, j)
                Next j
            Next i
            'Add new student to array and set their attendance to 1
            arrClass(UBound(arrClass), 0) = strName
            arrClass(UBound(arrClass), 1) = 1
        End If
    Next rw
Next sht

'Check for students with good attendance
For i = 0 To UBound(arrClass)
    If arrClass(i, 1) >= goodAttendance Then
        'Add first student
        If arrGood(0) = "" Then
            arrGood(0) = arrClass(i, 0)
        'Add subsequent students
        Else
            ReDim Preserve arrGood(0 To UBound(arrGood) + 1)
            arrGood(UBound(arrGood)) = arrClass(i, 0)
        End If
        strStudents = strStudents + arrClass(i, 0) + ", "
    End If
Next i

'Display students meeting criteria
If Len(strStudents) > 0 Then
    strStudents = Left(strStudents, Len(strStudents) - 2)
    MsgBox ("Students with more than " & goodAttendance & " attendances: " & strStudents)
Else
    MsgBox ("No students had at least " & goodAttendance & " attendances.")
End If

End Sub
```